# how to merge specific cells table data in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation

I want to condionally concatenate text cells in oracle table according to sequence (SEQ) number attribute. Is it possible to do it? I need your help with the query.

For example I have the following table DATA:

```
|-----------------|
|ID|CODE|SEQ|TEXT |
|--|----|---|-----|
|1 |a   |1  |text1|
|1 |a   |2  |text2|
|2 |b   |1  |text3|
|3 |c   |1  |text4|
|4 |d   |1  |text6|
|4 |d   |2  |text7|
|4 |d   |3  |text8|
-------------------
```

What I want to do is to create a new table DATA1 which concatenates TEXT values having the same id and code with concatenated texts in case SEQ > 1. The new table should look like this:

```
|-------------------------|
|ID|CODE|TEXT             |
|--|----|-----------------|
|1 |a   |text1 text2      |
|2 |b   |text3            |
|3 |c   |text4            |
|4 |d   |text6 text7 text8|
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

[`listagg()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php) function might be used with grouping by id and code.

```
select id, code, 
       listagg(text,' ') within group (order by seq) as text
  from tab
 group by id, code
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/DHCMTS42570)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barabaros. I want to apply query for a huge table. Is there a way to do it with for loop? We can also use php if looping is hard inside sql

Comment: Hi @Konstantinos. Mostly this way is more preferable than using PL/SQL with looping which includes verbose scripts I think. And using cursors don't provide a performance gain for hugely populated tables.

Comment: @Konstantinos - you have it exactly wrong. Cursors, loops, controlling processes from the outside (through PHP) cause performance loss, sometimes very significant. Doing everything within the DB, as Barbaros has shown, is by far the preferred way. If it's taking "too long", you can be sure it will take much longer with the methods you mentioned. But ask yourself - WHY do you want to do what you requested in the first place? The new table you are creating violates the most basic principles of table design.

Comment: @mathguy... I need to concatenate texts from first table according to sequences. What do you recommend?

Comment: @Konstantinos - The solution proposed by Barbaros. Also, "I need to concatenate..." doesn't answer the higher-level question I asked. **Why** do you need to concatenate? Or, a better question - perhaps you must concatenate, for some reporting purpose; but why do you need to STORE the concatenated values in a separate **table** (on disk)? How are you going to keep the two tables in sync when changes are made to the original table? Perhaps you should create a VIEW, not a new table, from the code proposed by Barbaros.